# Terminate k8s pods faster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple Node.js server running on some Kubernetes pods. When I delete a deployment with:

```
kubectl delete deployment <deployment-name>
```

sometimes pods have a status of terminating for 5-8 seconds. Seems excessive - is there a way to kill them faster somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to *kill* them instead of [gracefully shutdown](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods), then:

```
kubectl delete deployment <deployment-name> --grace-period=0
```

Also, if you have any [`preStop` handlers configured](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers), you could investigate if they are causing any unnecessary delay.